# Which database should I use? Locally stored, about 20 writes per minute, 1 read per minute, will grow 15MB each day

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm building a self-tracking system to log e.g. my phone's accelerometer, the keys I type, my mouse activity, and so on.

So which database should I use? My research so far suggests SQLite3, because the database won't be very big - my calculations give around 1 million new (small) records per day, which should be around 15MB per day.

Some software I use already stores its data in an SQLite3 database; would I have to write much special-case code to use the two different types of databases, or would the same code suffice?

Comment: Personally I'd use MySQL but that is solely due to my familiarity with it over other RDBM options.

Comment: I guess a requirement is SQL-type database?

Comment: @NickWilde: MySQL is still more limited than most RDBMS and it's speed is no longer much better. But for single user, SQLite is better than any server beast.

Comment: SQLite3 is fine with large data. I use it regularly with databases on order of tens of gigabytes. It is pretty fast, but it has slow commit, so when you do many inserts it's absolutely necessary to wrap them in transaction.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest you keep using SQLite3: most applications that need an embedded database for local/client storage use it, and 20 writes per minutes doesn't sound to me like a lot, all the more so as from what you describe the writes are probably just inserts, which you can easily [batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5009740/395857) provided that you use SQLite 3.7.11 or up:

```
 INSERT INTO 'tablename'
      SELECT 'data1' AS 'column1', 'data2' AS 'column2'
UNION SELECT 'data3', 'data4'
UNION SELECT 'data5', 'data6'
UNION SELECT 'data7', 'data8'
```

Comment: No need for this complex SQL. Just put the inserts in a transaction. SQLite is very fast in most operations, but commit is slow. With proper use of transactions it is faster than most alternatives, without them it's unuseable.